# Calling register endpoint failed with error [Error: self signed certificate]

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, ca, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I am trying to follow the hyperledger fabric tutorials [1] and get the Node.js SDK running with my network. I have already successfully enrolled the admin on my ca server, however, when trying the next step (registering a new user), I get an error about using a self-signed certificate.

I don't even understand which certificate the error is referring to. 
The ones in use by the CA server are obviously self-signed, since they are root certs. The certificate of the adminIdentity comes from the CA server itself, obtained in the previous enrollment step.

The logs on my ca-server container don't contain any errors, firing off the request does not even produce any log entries there.

The (unaltered) sample code from `fabric-samples/fabcar` and `fabric-samples/basic-network` obviously work just fine. As far as I can tell the SDK code is functionally identical to the samples, so I suspect the error to hide somewhere in the configuration.

This is my `registerUser.js` file:

```
/*
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

'use strict';

const FabricCAServices = require('fabric-ca-client');
const { FileSystemWallet, X509WalletMixin } = require('fabric-network');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'fabric-network', 'connection.json');
const ccpJSON = fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8');
const ccp = JSON.parse(ccpJSON);

async function main() {
    try {

        // Create a new CA client for interacting with the CA.
        const caURL = ccp.certificateAuthorities['ca.org1.org'].url;
        const ca = new FabricCAServices(caURL);

        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'org1', 'wallet');
        const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the admin user.
        const adminExists = await wallet.exists('admin');
        if (adminExists) {
            console.log('An identity for the admin user "admin" already exists in the wallet');
            return;
        }

        // Enroll the admin user, and import the new identity into the wallet.
        const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: 'admin', enrollmentSecret: 'adminpw' });
        const identity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity('Org1MSP', enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());
        wallet.import('admin', identity);
        console.log('Successfully enrolled admin user "admin" and imported it into the wallet');

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to enroll admin user "admin": ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

...and my `connection.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "OrganisationOne",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.org",
                "peer1.org1.org"
            ],
      "certificateAuthorities": [
        "ca.org1.org"
      ]
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.org": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.org/tlsca/tlsca.org1.org-cert.pem"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.org"
            }
        },
        "peer1.org1.org": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:8051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.org/tlsca/tlsca.org1.org-cert.pem"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org1.org"
            }
        }
    },
  "certificateAuthorities": {
    "ca.org1.org": {
      "url": "https://localhost:7054",
      "caName": "ca.org1.org"
    }
  }
}
```

I expected the user to be successfully registered, instead I receive the following error:

`Failed to register user "user1": Error: Calling register endpoint failed with error [Error: self signed certificate]`

What can I do to fix this error or even get more helpful information about it?

Comment: can you add your enrollAdmin,configtx.yaml and registeruser.js as well.

Comment: see https://github.com/fogshot/so-questions/tree/master/57028888

Answer (score 0):

Specify this inside connection.json file in `certificateAuthorities` properties

```
 "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Hit it myself recently, and I should know better;)

The error is because the CLI enrolling the user doesn't like receiving back a self-signed cert from the CA. In many environments this is the default, so it's helpful to hear that the default changes to false in 1.4.10.